# Can R create a new folder with different file names everyday

Tags: r

Could anyone suggest, Can I create a folder through R and then create new files every day through R?

What I am trying to do is I have to update an excel file that will backup a column in a database every day. I want to place this R file in the Task scheduler which should run the file at a particular time and create a folder through R and file with that day's date on it and do the extraction.

Presently I manually run the R script and do the data extraction from that table.

Comment: Check out the `fs` package, it has a `dir_create()` function that will do just that, and you can combine it with `glue` to have the directory names auto-created however you want. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fs/vignettes/function-comparisons.html https://glue.tidyverse.org/

Comment: Or in base, `dir.create`, `Sys.Date`, and `paste` are basically all you need.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try that. Very kind of you to reply.